# A question about the proof of Liouville's theorem.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have  a question about the [proof of Liouville's theorem as given on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)).

If I assume that $f(z)$ is entire and bounded only on $B_r(0)$ for some $r$ > 0, then using the same idea of the proof above, why can't I conclude that $f$ is constant on the whole domain?

Comment: can you write the usual proof of Liouville's theorem ?

Comment: what do you mean the usual proof?

Comment: the proof that a bounded entire function is constant..

Comment: I do not really know what is the usual proof, can you just spot the problem of this proof?@user1952009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only assume that $f$ is bounded on some specific disc, you can't let $r \to \infty$ to get $a_k = 0$ (with notation as in the linked proof).

Note that if $f$ is entire, then $f$ is bounded on every disc since it is continuous. The bound on $f$ depends on the radius of the disc though in general.

Comment: Suppose that I have $R>0$ then $f =  \sum_0 ^\infty z^n \int _{B_R(0)}\frac{f(w)}{w} dw$, and $ \int _{B_r(0)}\frac{f(w)}{w} dw$, am I right? If this is right(which I do think is right), then I can sill use the same techniques as before.

Comment: @Keith as written that's not right at all. Likely you forgot a power of $n$. But the problem persists. For some $R>0$ you get a bound for the $n$ coefficient of $M/R^{n}$ and that's it. How would you continue?

Comment: @Keith as I said, write the usual proof of Liouville's theorem, and it will become obvious when it applies and when it doesn't

Comment: Sorry I do forget (n+1). I would not work on $R>0$. My thought is to use that $\int_{B_R(0)} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw = \int _{B_r(0)} \frac{f(w)}{w^{n+1}}dw$, then I can make $r$ arbitrarily small.

Comment: The smaller you make $r$, the *worse* the bound gets.

Comment: Why? $f(w)$ will be bounded by $M$ and $r$ will go to zero, which is the same situation as in the wiki proof. @mrf

Comment: Oh, gosh, I am being an idiot since $r$ needs to get larger and larger.